# Implementation of a large parallel algorithm for communication with a server

Tags: fpga, vhdl, verilog, parallel

I want to run a parallel algorithm I will implement in Verilog/VHDL and use a FPGA to run it.

I have some questions:

1. How can I make an http request to servers using an FPGA - should I use a computer and transfer the data to registers?
2. What are the parameters in an FPGA which indicate the number of registers I can use/define?
3. What are the parameters in an which indicate the number of nand gates I can use/define?
4. Which FPGA is the most powerful?
5. Is there any way to parallel 2 or more FPGAs?

Comment: Why do you believe that you need the "most powerful" FPGA for your algorithm?  It's very likely that your connection to the server (or the internet) will be your bottleneck (even the cheapest FPGAs can probably saturate a gigabit link), and that your budget can't afford the highest-end FPGAs (which can cost tens of thousands of dollars).

Comment: I'd be interested as to why you believe the application is a better for an FPGA than for a bunch of conventional processors.  That's not to say that FPGAs do not occasionally get used for such things (Wall Street, etc), but I think someone in a position to make the determination soundly would probably know the answers to the questions you have asked.

Comment: i think the application is better for bunch of fpga, since i want to make a specific http request and analyze the data parallelly and then merging each chunk of analyzed data.

Comment: There are several unrelated questions here. To get an answer, perhaps you should ask a single question, such as a request for solution approaches given your problem requirements and budget.

Comment: @ZoZo123 - that sounds more like an application for a large number of ordinary processors.  What unique capabilities do you require which an FPGA can provide that justify the far, far, more complicated development process for FPGAs vs conventional processors?  Once you start talking about something with as much complexity as HTTP, while state machines are not theoretically impossible, most people would put a soft core processor in the FPGA, which is going to be several times slower than a processor implemented in hard-wired silicon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Various ways, all will involve sending the data from the FPGA to something that can send via HTTP (e.g. microcontroller, PC, ...)
   As Kevin mentions you can implement an ethernet MAC core on the FPGA to handle things - depending on resources available (size of FPGA, percent used, etc) this might be the best solution.
2. You can use as many registers as you like up to the number present on the FPGA.
3. As above, as many gates as the FPGA has can be used. Typically an FPGA has a number of Logic cells which are composed of (very roughly) a register and 3/4/5/6 input LUT, which can be configured in various ways to implement your HDL.
   For example the Virtex-7 series is listed as having 2 Million logic cells. Compare this with a typical $10 FPGA which might have 100,000 logic cells.
4. Depends on your definition of "powerful" (e.g. size, speed, RAM, DSP, analog, etc) 
   Examples of "top of the range" FPGAs would probably include chips like [Virtex-7](http://www.xilinx.com/products/silicon-devices/fpga/virtex-7/) and [Stratix-V](http://www.altera.com/devices/fpga/stratix-fpgas/stratix-v/stxv-index.jsp). They are also priced accordingly ;-)
5. Yes - you can parallel as many FPGAs as you like. Just as you can connect as many 74 series chips as you like.

Comment: Not all will use a microcontroller or a PC.  In fact, there are a great many development boards with Ethernet chips: [Here](http://opencores.org/project,ethernet_tri_mode) is an 10/100/1000 Mbps Ethernet MAC in Verilog; the Digilent [Atlys](http://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?NavPath=2,400,836&Prod=ATLYS) and [Gensys](http://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?NavPath=2,400,819&Prod=GENESYS) both implement an Ethernet MAC on the FPGA, and go directly to the PHY over a GMII interface.  No PC or microcontroller is required.

Comment: @KevinVermeer: Agreed - The uC/PC were just random examples of the "something that can send via http". Certainly worth mentioning the MAC on FPGA option though as it's probably the best solution in many situations, thanks for pointing it out - I will update the answer. Good link there to the open core - I'll be saving that one for future use :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of large chips and boards with multiple chips that are likely above what most people can afford.  If you have to ask how much these things cost, most likely you can't afford them.  http://www.dinigroup.com/new/DN2076k10.php  http://www.dinigroup.com/new/DN7020k10.php

Comment: I think you can safely say - a very nice house or one of those boards!